# RPM macro and quotes

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I would like to include a file in a package with a directory which is dependendat on the system.

I define the directory with

```
%define completions_dir "%( pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion )"
```

and I can use it successfully for example

```
%install
make DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{nagiospluginsdir} MANDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_mandir} COMPLETIONDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{completions_dir} install
```

The problem is when I have to define the list of files

The file is there. The following works

```
%files
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/check_ssl_cert
```

If I use the variable

```
%files
%{completions_dir}/check_ssl_cert
```

I get the following error:

```
RPM build errors:
    More than one file on a line: /check_ssl_cert
```

To debug I tried with

```
%files
/%{completions_dir}/check_ssl_cert
%endif
```

and in this case I get

```
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/nagios-plugins-check_ssl_cert-2.20.0-0.fc35.x86_64/"/usr/share/bash-completion/completions"/check_ssl_cert
```

The path is correct but the quotes are a problem.

How do I include a file using a path defined with a macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the quotes:

```
%define completions_dir %( pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion )
```

instead of

```
%define completions_dir "%( pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion )"
```

As side note - you should use `%global` rather than `%define`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if `%{completions_dir}` is just the directory, by putting

```
%files
%{completions_dir}
```

does the job (the file is included in the RPM)